# Items in document rearrange upon save

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am using Codeigniter and MongoDB and I am just wondering about the order of items in a document.

When I first save (create) a new document I set the order of the items in one way, but when I do an update to the document the items get rearranged. Is this normal?

First save:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4e96bd063dc7937202000000"),
    "firstname": "James",
    "lastname": "Bond",
    "fullname": "James Bond",
    "followers": "",
    "following": "",
    "lastlogin_at": "2011-10-13 12:33:47"

}
```

Second save:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4e96bd063dc7937202000000"),
    "firstname": "James",
    "followers": "",
    "following": "",
    "fullname": "James Bond",
    "lastlogin_at": "2011-10-13 12:33:47",
    "lastname": "Bond"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be overly concerned with the order of items within the object. When you reference them you use the property name; they're not like columns in a SQL database where you would reference them by a column index. The order of properties in the DB shouldn't affect your code in any way ;)

Comment: So it is normal then? I am a mongodb newbie so I do not want to make silly mistakes :)

Comment: I would assume it's normal as I've heard other people ask about it and based on the way the data is stored I could see how changing a value might rearrange the data in the database